# Select query to display Date format as mmm dd yyyy hh:mm am in SQL server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I tried like this

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),100)

result is

```
____________________
Jun 12 2014  3:10PM
____________________
```

I need space between time {3:10PM}

SELECT QUERY TO DISPLAY DATE AS SHOWN BELOW

```
____________________
Jun 12 2014  3:10 PM
____________________
```

Comment: Do you want in mysql or sqlServer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datatime is in default format. Example

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(19), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 100)
```

Returns:

```
Jun 12 2014 12:21PM
```

You need to add a space to this just before the 18th character. This is done with stuff:

```
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(char(19), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 100), 18,0, ' ')
```

Result:

```
Jun 12 2014 12:21 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),100),'PM',' PM'),'AM',' AM')
```

This will work in both MySQL and SQL Server, although you really should tag your question with the correct one.

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(17), GETDATE(), 100)
+ ' ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE(), 9), 25, 2) AS DateTime {Thanks For ur Help}

Comment: Did you test my query, or any issues/errors while testing?

Comment: ya i tested in Sql server 2008 alltime it is displaying PM for AM also